# Excel Formula Lookup 2 Criteria variable against 2 Criteria Array

Tags: excel, formula, lookup

I was wondering whether anyone can point me in the right direction for lookup of 2 criteria against 2 other criteria in a separate table of lookup values to show the previous nearest date.

Source Table with criteria 1 & 2

| Criteria1 | Criteria2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Prod 1 | 01/02/20 | 01/01/20 |
| Prod 2 | 01/03/20 | ........ |
| Prod 3 | 01/04/20 | ........ |
| Prod 4 | 01/05/20 | ........ |

Using the criteria from the first 2 columns to return the result in the third column, I would use the "Prod 1" and also the "01/02/20" to find the previous date from the below table which would be "01/01/20"

| Product | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Prod 1 | 01/12/19 |
| Prod 1 | 01/01/20 |
| Prod 1 | 01/02/20 |
| Prod 1 | 01/03/20 |

I've tried a few formulas found online but they just seem to return a #name error when specifying the criteria.

=INDEX(array,MATCH(1,(criteria1=criteria_range1)*(date_criteria<date_criteria_range),0))

This is what i have for now, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider concatenating the data creating a unique identifier prior to looking up the value. The cell address can then be found and one (1) can be subtracted from the row. The only limitation in the formula I can think of is if it is the first value it would return the header. However, this could be handled with an if statement.

=CONCAT(B3," ",TEXT(C3,"MMDDYY"))
=IFNA(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(G:I,MATCH(A3,G:G,0)-1,3)),TRUE),"Not in Table")

[Data output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBrDU.png)

[Data output formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrPB6.png)